# Servidor DNS, devolver 127.0.0.1 cuando el ordenador que hace la consulta tiene la IP de la respuesta

Tags: dns

Tengo configurado **Raspbian** con una **Raspberry Pi**, que me hace de servidor **DHCP** y **DNS** (bind) entre otras cosas.

En el servidor **DNS** tengo configurados varios dominios internos como por ejemplo:

*www.midominio.local* que supongamos apunta a *192.168.0.80*

Como el servidor **DHCP** esta configurado que para que asigne, a los clientes, a si mismo como servidor **DNS**, todos los dispositivos en mi red reconocen y navegan a los dominios locales.

Lo que necesito saber, si es posible hacer es que cuando una solicitud al servidor **DNS** provenga de la **IP** de la respuesta retorne *127.0.0.1* en lugar de la **IP** de la subred, ejemplo:

Si el ordenador con *IP 192.168.0.80* consulta por el dominio *www.midominio.local*, en lugar de retornar *192.168.0.80*, que es lo que retornaría a los otros ordenadores, debe retornar *127.0.0.1*

Se que esto lo puedo solucionar escribiendo la entrada en el archivo hosts del ordenador en cuestión, pero me iría mejor que lo pudiese resolver el servidor DNS

Comment: Pregunta inocente: ¿Si un equipo consulta su propio nombre, la resolución de nombres pasa primero por `/etc/hosts` y por lo tanto no llegaría al DNS?

Comment: Si eso es lo que precisamente quiero evitar, el  tener que editar el  hosts para añadir la entrada.

Comment: Si quieres que tu computadora modifique un "comportamiento" estándar, necesariamente tienes que modificar tu computadora, ese archivo o cualquier otro, ¿estás de cuerdo? Si estás de acuerdo hay una alternativa, si no... pues no se me ocurre nada.

Comment: Ya deberías poder marcar como correcta tu propia respuesta. Hazlo para que quede registro de que esta pregunta está resuelta.

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado la solución, esta en inglés
https://serverfault.com/questions/332440/dns-bind-how-to-return-a-different-ip-based-on-requests-subnet

A partir de Bind 9 se puedes crear diferentes vistas para que devuelvan diferentes IP información según el  cliente

```
view "developer" {
        match-clients { 192.168.1.155; };
        include "/etc/named.conf.zones-rfc1912";
        include "/etc/named.conf.zones-common";
        include "/etc/named.conf.zones-developer";
};
// sin match-clients es el resto
view "all" {    
        include "/etc/named.conf.zones-rfc1912";
        include "/etc/named.conf.zones-common";
        include "/etc/named.conf.zones-developer-for-all";
};
```

Esto me permite configurar los dominios que necesite que apunten a 127.0.0.1 para el ordenador de desarrollo y la IP de ese ordenador para el resto.